# How to handle colored input in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am running the command module on ansible which receives a colored output from the command it's running (img2txt) and stores it in a register.
When I display register.stdout in ansible I received this garbled output.
Is there a way to tell ansible that the output from command is colored?

```
- name: Decode the power meter jpg to text
  command:
    cmd: img2txt -g 0.1 -W 50 "{{ JpgFileName }}"
  changed_when: False
  register: Img2Txt_result

- name: Print text power meter readout
  debug:
    msg: "{{ Img2Txt_result.stdout }}"
```

Here's the output I receive in ansible:

```
    "msg": "\u001b[0;34;40m                                                  
\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;34;40m                                                  
\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;34;40m                                             
\u001b[0;32;40m \u001b[0;34;40m    \u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;34;40m                                             
\u001b[0;32;40m \u001b[0;34;40m    \u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;34;40m                                                  
\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;34;40m                                                  
\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;34;40m                                                  
\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;34;40m
```

Thanks,

Comment: I guess I should have searched for [your program's man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/img2txt.1.html) to learn that **its whole job** is to output ANSI escape codes -- so what, exactly, are you expecting to happen here? You want your playbook to display ANSI on your terminal?

Comment: ```You want your playbook to display ANSI on your terminal?``` Yes that is correct. Simply put - if you run img2txt on a terminal on the native machine you get a color output, and I want to see the same thing if I were to run it through ansible. Thanks.

Comment: then you'll need a custom [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list) because all of the provided ones quote characters before displaying them to your console

Comment: ```then you'll need a custom callback plugin```  I was afraid of that - I was hoping that ansible had a function that did it automatically. Thanks anyway for looking into this for me.

Comment: The default callback plugin does display ANSI color codes. Do you have a different `stdout_callback` defined in your ansible.cfg?

Comment: I take this back, I think (can't edit above), `ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS=1 ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible --verbose localhost --module-name shell -a 'echo -e '\''\e[0;31mExample\e[0m foo'\'''` outputs/renders a yellow "changed" task with a red "example" and black "foo". But using the shell module in a playbook just displays the ANSI Codes without a render. Something is different with a playbook run vs ad-hoc Ansible.

Comment: I forgot, we are using Jenkins and the "Ansicolor" plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansicolor-plugin, which works with Ansible, but not the nested ANSI codes returning in that sub-output.